# Undefined control sequence. \maketitle

Tags: titles

This is a template that worked fine a few months ago. I just downloaded and installed Miktex again and using this as template now to create a new report but it won't compile even the original one again.

```
% Set up the document
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\graphicspath{Figures/}  % Location of the graphics files (set up for graphics to be in PDF format)
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}  % Colours hyperlinks in blue, but this can be distracting if there are many links.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{headings}
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter      % Begin Roman style (i, ii, iii, iv...) page numbering
% Set up the Title Page
\title  {SEMINAR NAME}
\authors  {\texorpdfstring
            {\href{XYZ@gmail.com}{STUDENT NAME}}
            {STUDENT NAME}
            }
\addresses  {\ BACHELOR OF ENGINNERING \newline COMPUTER ENGINEERING \newline SAVITRIBAI PHULE PUNE UNIVERSITY}  % Do not change this here, instead these must be set in the "Thesis.cls" file, please look through it instead
\date       {APRIL-MAY 2015}
\subject    {}
\keywords   {}
\maketitle
\clearpage
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\setstretch{1.3}  % It is better to have smaller font and larger line spacing than the other way round
% Define the page headers using the FancyHdr package and set up for one-sided printing
\fancyhead{}  % Clears all page headers and footers
\rhead{\thepage}  % Sets the right side header to show the page number
\lhead{}  % Clears the left side page header
\pagestyle{fancy}  % Finally, use the "fancy" page style to implement the FancyHdr headers
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Declaration Page required for the Thesis, your institution may give you a different text to place here
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}}  % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics
\chapter*{\centerline{Certificate}}
\par
This is to certify that the following student of T.E. Computer, Vishwakarma Institute of Information Technology, Pune\\
\vspace{0.3in}
\centerline{ “ NAME OF THE STUDENT”}\\
\vspace{0.3in}
has successfully completed the Seminar and Technical Communication Report on\\
\vspace{0.3in}
\centerline{“ SEMINAR NAME ”}\\
\vspace{0.3in}
in the partial fulfillment of the requirements for the completion of T.E. in Computer Engineering in 2015 as prescribed by the Savitribai Phule Pune University.\\

\vspace{1.0in}
Prof. GUIDE NAME \hspace{3.1in} Dr S.R.SAKHARE
Guide \hspace{4.6in}   H.O.D. 
\centerline{\vspace{0.10in}\noindent Dr.B.S.KARKARE}
\centerline{\noindent Principal}
\vspace{0.25in}\noindent Date :
\vspace{0.15in}\noindent Place: Pune 
\clearpage  % Declaration ended, now start a new page
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% The "Funny Quote Page"
\pagestyle{empty}  % No headers or footers for the following pages
%\null\vfill
% Now comes the "Funny Quote", written in italics
\clearpage  % Funny Quote page ended, start a new page
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Error - Undefined control sequence. \maketitle

Has latex changed it's use of \maketitle recently?

Comment: `\maketitle`would be defined (or not) by the document class in use, you are using a non standard class `Thesis.cls`and given no link to it so it is impossible to say what should work or not.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle
Thanks. Sorry about that

[Thesis.cls] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mvXn-oW3tHdQHNZqTQg4FM9ndatE4E14/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `Thesis.cls` uses in `\maketitle` a command `\logo` not defined anywhere.

Comment: **Correction**. It does compile. But always gives that error.

https://www.overleaf.com/4697366549ywygfcbdkyjx